# Banner to warn about AI generated content

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-review, ai-generated-content

As per [this question on Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/395881/249769), we now have the ability to request a banner for AI content. There are two banners which could be had:

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools are not allowed on Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Learn more

or

> **Reminder**: Answers generated by Artificial Intelligence tools must be cited on Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair. Learn more

I'm personally more fond of the first rendition where we would not allow AI generated content at all. This banner would be posted in place of where it would normally say "New User" just below the user's signature block.

While I don't think we've seen that a lot of AI generated content, I'm sure it could be here and personally I'd like to not have it here on the site. This, however, is up to the community and not me as a mod. To that end, I post the question asking what the user base would like to see have happen. Please post an answer below with your leanings along with an explanation, or upvote someone else's take on it with an upvote or dislike for same with a downvote.

Comment: To the CM: While there's not a lot of action here, I'd personally still like to press forward with having it. Nothing negative was posted, so I'm going with people aren't against it.

Answer (score 3):

Go for the first option - banning AI answers.

I can't see AI answers being posted often in the forseeable future.  I wouldn't trust it to give an accurate answer to something that is as safety related as working on a vehicle.  So I wouldn't want to see any AI output here.